# how to pass data or string while popviewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am navigating 6 navigations down..and from sixth navigation page i want to transfer something(some string value) to First PAge .If i continue the navigation the navigation controller maintains  the stack and while going back i have to come across all previous navigated views. If i am popping from Sixth navigation view to First it is not carrying any value.How to do this..any another logic to carry string or data ?or to clear the navigation controller Stack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to send information you might want to go through the app delegate or create a custom delegate that you wire up in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new method in the AppDelegate (ex. `-(void)didChangeSixthPageString`), then call it from `SixthPageViewController`. In the AppDelegate you probably have a reference to the the first view controller, so you can pass it the string.